# How to get height from header ( bytes array ) of mp4 file

Tags: mp4

I have problem that, Im downloading just header of file ( 8000 bytes or I can take more ). Then from those bytes array Im trying to identify it and get height of video.
When for AVI is simple and I see it then for mp4 I can find this resolution.. Anyone familiar with it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ive found nice source code which helped me:

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/c869d076e9cd42aba5a3e35d88827610dec6ca15/examples/src/main/java/com/google/code/mp4parser/example/GetHeight.java